# Loop through 2 model objects at once rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iterator, mysql2

I have a users object that I'm exposing through the simple call:

```
@users = User.all
```

I also have some more expensive queries I'm doing where I'm using custom SQL to generate the results.

```
@comment_counts = User.received_comment_counts
```

This call and others like it will return  objects with one element per user in my list ordered by id.

In my view I'd like to loop through the users and the comment_counts object at the same time. Eg:

```
for user, comment_count in @users, @comment_counts do
end
```

I can't figure out how to do this. I also can't seem to figure out how to get an individual record from the @comment_counts result without running it through @comment_counts.each

Isn't there some way to build an iterator for each of these lits objects, dump them into a while loop and step the iterator individually on each pass of the loop? Also, if you can answer this where can I go to learn about stepping through lists in rails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
@users.zip(@comment_counts).each do |user, comments_count|
  # Do something
end
```

I've never come across manual manipulation of iterators in Ruby, not to say that it can't be done.  Code like that would likely be messy and so I would likely favor more elegant solutions.

Comment: @comment_counts is a Mysql2::Result so I get the error - can't convert Mysql2::Result into Array. This is really interesting though.

Comment: Ah, you'll need to get the data out of your query result for `@comment_counts` first.  If you are unfamiliar with that there is an example here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.3.6/frames

Comment: That did the trick - and the rubydoc.info reference was useful thankya!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the arrays have equal values:

In your controller:

```
@users = User.all
@comments = Comment.all
```

In your view.

```
<% @users.each_with_index do |user, i |%>
    <% debug user %>
    <% debug @comments[i] %>
<% end %>
```

Then you can just check if the values exists on `@comments` if you don't know if the arrays have the same number of objects.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious because your data requires a bit of restructuring. `comment_count` clearly belongs to instances of `User` and this should be reflected so that only loop on one collection (of `User`s) is necessary. I can think of two possible ways to achieve this:

1. [Eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). *Only works for associated models*, not the case here probably. Say, each of your users has `comments`, so writing `User.includes(:comments).all` would return all users with their comments and only do 2 queries to fetch the data.
2. For counting each user's comments you could just use [`counter_cache` (clickable)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). Then you'll have one more field in the `users` table for caching how many comments a user has. Again, works for associated `Comment`s only.